# how to overcome the slow pace of my simulink model?

Tags: simulation, matlab, simulink

I have run the solver profiler to debug where my simulink model stuck and take very long time to simulate. I found out it is the diode model that I model as following:
[image]

It runs fast on its own. However, in the big simulink model it sticks for 30 min. I tried a simple function block ans shows same result.

Comment: I'd suggest considering what the implication of large di/dt values does to the rest of the system. Diodes, even simplified but non-ideal ones, do not turn on and off instantaneously like your switch approximation does. Partly because it's not a good representation but also because the 'snappiness' of a diode like this implies infinite di/dt values which in-turn imply that infinite dv/dt values have caused them  and if you're lucky you only get oscillations and small time steps but it'll often cause a solver to fail to converge.

Comment: I just removed the diode just to see. but, seems same problem, too slow. i will proceed block by block and report it here